# How to turn CT segmentation into 3d model in python

Tags: python, 3d, blender, vtk, mayavi.mlab

I have this numpy array of slices of segments of the liver CT(ground truths). I want to export them into a viewable format in tools like blender. The slices are white and black, 0-255. Anything other than liver is black, I want the liver to be viewed in 3d.

The slices are in top view. I used this code in kaggle to view them but just in jupyter https://www.kaggle.com/akh64bit/full-preprocessing-tutorial/data. It can be any way to visualize them.

Comment: Do you have a specific issue? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, eh.

Comment: [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/48919/935) may provide some insight. Using 2.79 blender render supports an image sequence for [voxel data](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/textures/types/volume/voxel_data.html). You may also create vertices out of your array and use the [point density node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/render/shader_nodes/textures/point_density.html).

Answer (score 1):

You may try transform your arrays to DICOM format as mentioned before in stackoverflow: [Create pydicom file from numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350675/create-pydicom-file-from-numpy-array)

Than you can easily visualize DICOM images in various platforms!

Answer (score 1):

For new folks stumbling upon this question that are looking to convert pixels / voxels to an STL file or files, this Python workflow has worked for me:

1. Load stack of images as a 3D [NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/) array using [imageio.imread()](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/v2.16.1/_autosummary/imageio.imread.html).
2. Segment the foreground from the background using one of the many segmentation algorithms from the [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/) submodule [skimage.segmentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.segmentation), creating a 3D binary image.
3. Use the [marching cubes algorithm](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.marching_cubes) from the scikit-image submodule `skimage.measure` to convert the voxels of interest to a list of faces defined by vertices on the surface of the volume.
4. Use [numpy-stl](https://numpy-stl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create an `stl.Mesh` object from the list of faces and vertices (as done in [this example](https://numpy-stl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#creating-mesh-objects-from-a-list-of-vertices-and-faces)) then save the mesh with `stl.Mesh.save()`.

As a bonus, you can use the Python package for the [Open3D](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/) library to open & view multiple STL files!